# Hyperref warning when using amsthm and enumerate

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lists, theorems, warnings

`hyperref` gives the warning that something has been referenced but it doesn't exist. When I use the `enumerate` (or an `itemize`) list, I get the warning. Here is the minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{Bem}{Bemerkung}
\begin{document}
\begin{Bem}
\label{Bemelm}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{Bem}
\ref{Bemelm}
\end{document}
```

When I use `cleveref` or just don't use `hyperref` it gives no warning.

Answer (score 4):

LaTeX is in a funny state if you start one list environment immediately inside another, hyperref ends up referencing an internal label that it never actually uses.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{Bem}{Bemerkung}
\begin{document}
\begin{Bem}
\mbox{}\label{Bemelm}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item 
\end{enumerate}
\end{Bem}
\ref{Bemelm}
\end{document}
```

Makes the error go away but also changes the layout. If you want the original layout, I'd need to look harder:-)

Comment: look harder ;-)

Comment: `\phantomsection` instead of the \mbox{} seems to work.