# Wrong cross-references and warnings

Tags: cross-referencing, warnings

I get a warning if I compile this code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[satz]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{bemerkung}[satz]{Bemerkung}

\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
Let's go to the next page.
\clearpage
\begin{bemerkung}\label{bem:1}
\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{bemerkung}

As we have seen in Bemerkung~\ref{bem:1}...
\end{document}
```

If i click on the reference I am at page 1 and not at the 'Bemerkung'.
Has somebody an idea what the problem could be?

Thank you!

Comment: *What is the warning?* I suspect you need to rerun LaTeX to get the bookmarks right -- cross-referencing generally needs two passes, sometimes more.

Comment: The warning is: name{satz.3.3} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110297/hyperref-warning-when-using-amsthm-and-enumerate

Comment: I have already seen that but as mentioned in this post, the layout is changed: The items start in a new line. Can you undo that?

Answer (score 1):

The nested `list` environments (itemize) and `bemerkung` confuse `hyperref` when a `\label` command is issued.

Use a `\mbox{}` to jump out of the current mode, the following `\label` is placed correctly afterwards, as well as the hyperanchor.

Interestingly, using `cleveref` this `\mbox{}` command isn't necessary at all (I recommend this here anyway).

Alternative solution: Explicitly use a `\phantomsection` before `\label`, but this can become tedious.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}


\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}

\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}[section]
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[satz]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{bemerkung}[satz]{Bemerkung}

\usepackage[ngerman]{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref} %If used then after hyperref is loaded!

\begin{document}
Let's go to the next page.
\section{Foo}
\clearpage
\begin{bemerkung}
\mbox{}%
\label{bem:1}

\begin{itemize}
\item item 1
\item item 2
\item item 3
\end{itemize}

\end{bemerkung}

As we have seen in Bemerkung~\ref{bem:1}...
\end{document}
```