# How to avoid an hyperref bug (?) in theorems

Tags: hyperref, amsthm

Sometimes in AMS theorems we use lists. For some reason, when the list arrives just after the `\label` at the very beginning of the theorem, the hyperref link is corrupted. It suffices to put a single character or a `\leavevmode` and the hyperref is OK, but of course the first entry of the itemize list is not anymore the first line of the theorem, and this is precisely what I need.

Compare:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}
\author{Yannis}
\title{Titre}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{coro}\label{blabla}
\begin{itemize}\item This is a corollary.\item With a list\end{itemize}
\end{coro}

As we saw in Corollary~\ref{blabla}\ldots

\end{document}
```

In the result (I tried it on both on my Mac and on overleaf, both with TeXlive 2020) the hyperref link points to the title of the document. When I write

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref,amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}
\author{Yannis}
\title{Titre}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{coro}\label{blabla}\leavevmode
\begin{itemize}\item This is a corollary.\item With a list\end{itemize}
\end{coro}

As we saw in Corollary~\ref{blabla}\ldots

\end{document}
```

the the hyperref link is OK but the list starts one line lower.

How can I have both entry starting on the same line as the corollary and a correct hyperref link?

Comment: Can't test now but try replacing `\leavevmode` by `\phantomsection`. Unrelated: `hyperref` should (almost) always be loaded last.

Comment: There is obviously something wrong here. I can get it to work if `cleveref` is loaded after `hyperref` (though I usually never use `cleveref` so something is up here).

Comment: @daleif Only similar thing I've found is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110297/82917

Comment: OK so the bug was known already in 2016… Thanks for the information, the cleveref tip solved the problem!

Comment: Not necessarily a bug, but definitely a potential problem.  This is described in the user's guide for `amthm` in the section 2.1, "Theorems beginning with lists".  It was known long before 2016.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is a known problem, but hyperref can't do much here currently (and don't want to) as the problem is in amsthm. See also https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/48

As mentioned in the comment, cleveref patches `\@thm` and so resolves the problem. So loading the package is one option. The other is to set the missing target manually:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{coro}{Corollary}
\author{Yannis}
\title{Titre}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

xxxxx

\begin{coro}\label{blabla}\hypertarget{\csname @currentHref\endcsname}{}%\leavevmode

\begin{itemize}\item This is a corollary.\item With a list\end{itemize}
\end{coro}

\newpage
As we saw in Corollary~\ref{blabla}\ldots

\end{document}
```

That a target is missing can be seen in the log:

```
 pdfTeX warning (dest): name{coro.1} has been referenced but does not exist, replaced by a fixed one
```

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, the tip with cleveref solved the problem. Even though it is a bit sad to load packages not for their features but because they allow avoiding bugs of other packages… Could TeXLive maybe have some mechanism to advise people “when you use hyperref and amsthm, think of using cleveref as well” ??